# base_convert numbers map to letters

Tags: php, base-conversion

How can I use base_convert to map numbers to letters?

for example 123456 would become ABCDEF.
So a number 123321 would become ABCCBA

I actually have a unique number, that needs to keep it's uniqueness in the form of a string of letters. Any way to do this?

Comment: hash it with the likes of md5() perhaps?

Comment: it can be a sequance of up to 21 numbers

Answer (score 8):

[`base_convert()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) is for converting numbers between different number systems. Like Hex to Bin.

For your task is [`strtr()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php):

```
$original = '13421';
$replaced = strtr($original, '12345', 'ABCDE');
echo $replaced; // output: ACDBA
```

As you see `strtr` works like a *char-wise* translator. If a char out of the `$from` string is found in the input string, it will be translated by the char that is at the same position of the `$to` string. However, it's better explained by the code example above :)

Comment: what do you mean with any length of number?

Comment: @gray strtr stands for string translate. essentially it translates one set of characters to another by replacing each letter in the second argument (`12345`) to the letter in the same spot in the third argument (`ABCDE`).